# Valgrind errors with dynamic arrays of struct in other strust

Tags: c, valgrind

I have struct like:

```
typedef struct Sentense{
    long int length;
    wchar_t *str;
    wchar_t **splword;
    long int count_words;
    long long int prod;
} sentense_s;

typedef struct Text{
    long int quant;
    sentense_s *sent;
} text_s;
```

And functions for reading text and working with it:

```
#ifndef MAKE_BIG
#define MAKE_BIG 10
#endif

int read_str(wchar_t **str){
    int avl_sy = MAKE_BIG;
    int symb = 0;
    *str = (wchar_t *)malloc(avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (!str)
        return 1;
    wchar_t input = '.';
    while (input != L'\n'){
        wscanf(L"%lc", &input);
        if (avl_sy <= symb){
            avl_sy += MAKE_BIG;
            *str = (wchar_t*)realloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));
            if (!str)
                return 1;
        }
        (*str)[symb] = input;
        symb++;
    }
    (*str)[symb] = L'\0';
    return 0;
}

int make_arr(wchar_t *temp, text_s *text){
    temp[wcslen(temp) - 1] = L'\0';
    text->quant = 0;
    long int avl_sent = MAKE_BIG;
    text->sent = (sentense_s *)malloc(avl_sent * sizeof(sentense_s));
    if (!text->sent)
        return 1;
    wchar_t *token = NULL;
    wchar_t *buffer = NULL;
    token = wcstok(temp, L".", &buffer);
    while (token != NULL){
        if (avl_sent <= text->quant){
            avl_sent += MAKE_BIG;
            text->sent = (sentense_s *)realloc(text->sent, avl_sent * sizeof(sentense_s));
            if (!text->sent)
                return 1;
        }
        text->sent[text->quant].str = (wchar_t *)malloc( (wcslen(token) + 2) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        if (!text->sent[text->quant].str)
            return 1;
        wmemcpy(text->sent[text->quant].str, token, wcslen(token) + 1);
        text->quant++;
        token = wcstok(NULL, L".", &buffer);
    }
    token = NULL;
    buffer = NULL;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

And there are two problems:
1) In some test it crashes at the begging of program with:

```
main: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

But then I start is second time it works.
2) Valgrind show me this errors:

```
==11408== Invalid write of size 4
==11408==    at 0x109462: read_str (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x109296: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==  Address 0x4a86878 is 0 bytes after a block of size 680 alloc'd
==11408==    at 0x4839D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==11408==    by 0x109410: read_str (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x109296: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408== 
==11408== Invalid read of size 4
==11408==    at 0x483FE24: wcslen (vg_replace_strmem.c:1868)
==11408==    by 0x1094AE: make_arr (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x1092C1: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==  Address 0x4a86878 is 0 bytes after a block of size 680 alloc'd
==11408==    at 0x4839D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==11408==    by 0x109410: read_str (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x109296: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408== 
==11408== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11408==    at 0x48389AB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==11408==    by 0x1092E5: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==  Address 0x4a865d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 680 free'd
==11408==    at 0x48389AB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==11408==    by 0x1096B7: make_arr (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x1092C1: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==  Block was alloc'd at
==11408==    at 0x4839D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==11408==    by 0x109410: read_str (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==    by 0x109296: main (in /home/nikita/GitHub/Course-work/Code/main)
==11408==
```

Where is my mistakes? Why it works strange with dynamic array of structs?

It's temp from main:

```
wchar_t *temp;
```

Comment: Don't `realloc` the pointer itself, e.g. don't `*str = (wchar_t*)realloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));`, instead `void *tmp = ealloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t)); if (!tmp) { /* handle error */ } *str = tmp;`

Comment: `if (!str)         return 1;` is meaningless as you already deferenced `str`. May be you wanted to check `if(!*str)` after mallocing.

Comment: I suspect your 4-byte problem is due to being one or two `wchar_t` too short on one of your allocations and then attempting to write to that location and a similar read thereafter. It is almost impossible to know for sure without something I can compile and test. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `temp[wcslen(temp) - 1] = L'\0';` are you sure `temp` is already terminated with `\0`? as I see you are terminating the `temp` after calling `wcslen` which is wrong. `wcslen` needs input `wchar *` to be `\0` terminated.

Comment: (that would also go to explaining the Invalid Read - `at 0x483FE24: wcslen (vg_replace_strmem.c:1868)`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I believe so.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I use it to delete '\n' from input str. And yes, I was already terminated. Is correct this way?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm sorry, can you pls tell how to do this temp correct? Because then I make 'void *tmp' and 'tmp = realloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));' I start to have a lot errors like  "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)".

Comment: Sure, you are protecting against `realloc` returning `NULL` and overwriting your pointer causing a memory leak. You simply use a temporary pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));`. You then validate `tmp` is not `NULL` or handle the error, e.g. `if (tmp == NULL) { perror ("realloc-str"); break; }` (or use `goto`) Now if `tmp` passes and is not `NULL`, just assign the reallocated block to `*str`, e.g. `*str = tmp;`. This allows you to validate the `realloc` call while avoiding the memory leak in case of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access out bound here.

```
   while (input != L'\n'){
        wscanf(L"%lc", &input);
        if (avl_sy <= symb){
            avl_sy += MAKE_BIG;
            *str = (wchar_t*)realloc(*str, avl_sy * sizeof(wchar_t));
            if (!str)
                return 1;
        }
        (*str)[symb] = input;
        symb++;
    }
    (*str)[symb] = L'\0';
```

Consider you inputted `\n` when `symb=9` and `if (avl_sy <= symb)` condition is false and you will not re-allocate.

Now `symb++;` will make `symb=10` and break out of the loop as `input == '\n'`.

```
    (*str)[symb] = L'\0';//(*str)[10] out of bound access.
```